# Deploying SXA 10.2 XM Single with Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.7 - The path '' is not valid for the 'dbDacFx' provider

Tags: sxa, paas, arm-template

When I attempt to deploy a Sitecore 10.2 XM0 topology with JSS 19.0 and SXA 10.2 configured as modules, I receive this error during the SXA deployment step:

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "Failed",
        "message": "Package deployment failed\r\nARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The path '' is not valid for the 'dbDacFx' provider. ---&gt; System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions.set_Path(String value)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ManifestProvider.&lt;GetPostProvidersHelper&gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebDeployEventHelper.EventWriteManifest(String sessionId, DeploymentObjectProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()'"
    }
}
```

This answer in another, related question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/9280/3053, suggests that the issue is related to the wrong topology being used.  For this reason I've included my obfuscated module parameters in case I have lost my mind:

```
{
  "name": "sxa",
  "templateLink": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/SXA%2010.2.0/xm0/azuredeploy.json",
  "parameters": {
    "cmSxaMsDeployPackageUrl" : "https://XXXXXXX/Sitecore Experience Accelerator XM 10.2.0 rev. 04247.scwdp.zip",
    "speMsDeployPackageUrl" : "https://XXXXXXX/Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.3.scwdp.zip",
    "solrCorePrefix" : "sitecore"
  }
}
```

I tried to install Sitecore 10.1.1 XM0 with SXA 10.1 and got the exact same error, which leads me to believe that either:

1. I don't know what I'm doing with these ARM templates
2. SAT 2.7 has a problem and I should try SAT 2.6
3. SXA isn't designed to be deployed in the XM0 topology

Comment: I have attempted the same install using the XM Scaled topology with the same results.  Taking this to a Sitecore Support ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore support got back to me a lot quicker than I anticipated.  They pointed out that I was not using the IAR deployment package for Powershell Extensions located here:

[https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/D1EDF3410DA34E109CBACAFD424952EC.ashx?date=20211103T111147](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/D1EDF3410DA34E109CBACAFD424952EC.ashx?date=20211103T111147)

Once I updated my module parameters to use the correct web deploy package, I was able to get my environment successfully provisioned.

```
{
  "name": "sxa",
  "templateLink": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/SXA%2010.2.0/xm0/azuredeploy.json",
  "parameters": {
    "cmSxaMsDeployPackageUrl" : "https://XXXXXXX/Sitecore Experience Accelerator XM 10.2.0 rev. 04247.scwdp.zip",
    "speMsDeployPackageUrl" : "https://XXXXXXX/Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.3 - IAR.scwdp.zip",
    "solrCorePrefix" : "sitecore"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was that i was pointing to SCWDP's for a topology different that was i was deploying.

> It was because I used the xM topology templates with the scwdp-files
>   I’ve downloaded for the xP-topology. The latter one depends on a
>   reporting database, which the xM templates don’t send as parameter.
>   Make sure that you use the packages with the same topology of
>   templates.